# Stack View, Collapse Space to Content

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

I have a vertical StackView with three nested Labels

- Stack View

  - PlusMinus (Label)
  - Currency (Label)
  - Amount (Label)

The content in the labels are dynamic. I want the stack view to have the 3 items to be next to each other with very minimal spacing in between each other. Such that an example values would read something like "+ $ 45.67", but it seems that all Distribution options under Stack View do not accomplish this. The individual font and color settings under each label are different, so I can not simply use 1 label for these.

Is there anyway to say that each column in a vertical stack view must only take up how much space is taken up by a nested Label.

Comment: You should really post more information on what you have tried but I suggest you need to look into setting the content hugging and compression resistance for the UILabels appropriately and setting the text alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the content hugging and the text alignment of the labels appropriately.

So if the whole thing is to be right aligned you do this:

```
    self.signLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 300), for: .horizontal)
    self.currencyLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 400), for: .horizontal)
    self.valueLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 500), for: .horizontal)
    self.signLabel.textAlignment = .right
    self.currencyLabel.textAlignment = .right
    self.valueLabel.textAlignment = .right
```

and if it is to be left aligned you do this:

```
    self.signLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 500), for: .horizontal)
    self.currencyLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 400), for: .horizontal)
    self.valueLabel.setContentHuggingPriority(.init(rawValue: 300), for: .horizontal)
    self.signLabel.textAlignment = .left
    self.currencyLabel.textAlignment = .left
    self.valueLabel.textAlignment = .left
```

(you can vary the numbers as long as they stay in the increasing order).

What this does is to give the layout system clues as to which of the UILabels should compress down to hug it's content first.

This should work with a UIStackView set to horizontal and using the default settings.

Comment: I actually only had to edit the this in the storyboard view, no code required. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that it could all be done in the storyboard.  Still glad it's all working now.